# How do I use the outputs from lapply function in another function?

Tags: r, list, loops

Lets say this command outputs 100 dendrogram objects where function1 is the hierarchical clustering procedure

```
dendy <- lapply(1:100, function1)
```

I would like to put these objects into a `dendlist`

```
dend.l <- dendlist(dendy[[1]],dendy[[2]],dendy[[3]],dendy[[4]],dendy[[5]],...,
                   dendy[[100]]
```

is what I'm after. Instead of writing all `dendy[[1]],...,dendy[[100]]` how would I put the 100 dendy objects in the `dendlist` function?

Comment: Try `do.call(dendlist, dendy)`.

Comment: `Map(dendlist, dendy)`

Comment: @nachoes seems to work well.

Comment: @YOLO the map function seems to just output dendy, it's not classifying it as a dendlist. Nethertheless do.call fixed the problem. Thanks for the help